# How to post data to Google Fusion Tables automatically AngularJS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to create a map with polygons using Google Fusion Tables. Instead of importing the data manually each time when there are new entries, I want to automatize it with AngularJS/Javascript.

My question is, how do I post and handle (through a controller or factory) the data automatically to a Fusion Table in AngularJS/Javascript? Does anyone know a good example or way to start? Do I need to work with JSON and if so how would that look like?

EDIT:
I already have retrieved the data from another API with the following controller:

```
.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.entries = [];

    $http.get('main.json').success(function(data) {

      angular.forEach(data.ParkingFacilities, function(entry) {

         $http.get(entry.staticDataUrl).success(function(data) {

            $scope.entries.push(angular.extend(entry, data.parkingFacilityInformation));

         });
      });

    });

  });
```

An example of the JSON file is available here: https://npropendata.rdw.nl/parkingdata/v2/

Comment: Where is "the data" coming from? Another API?

Comment: Yes, I retrieve the data from another API (JSON file), save it, and then want to push it to the Fusion Tables such that my Google Maps Fusion table is automatically updated.

Comment: See my latest EDIT for what is already in place.